# How to save winring mode window configuration in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Recently I started using winring mode and it does perfectly what I wanted : Named window configurations. It does not remember the configuration across new emacs sessions. Is there a way to make these persistent across sessions?

Answer (score 2):

[Workgroups for Windows](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el#readme) persists window configuration across sessions, and the experimental branch introduces support for workgroup-granular buffer lists.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this kind of thing is to hook into `desktop.el`, which is almost certainly built into your emacs:

```
(setq desktop-save 'if-exists)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'some-var-you-want-to-save)
```

However, it looks like winring's config is stored in per-frame properties, not regular variables, so it won't be usable by `desktop.el`.

Short of hacking winring, you're probably out of luck. Perhaps try one of the alternatives like `revive` or `escreen`.